# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'db' was corrupted. c++ (Help)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

I'm getting this error while trying to launch my application, I've isolated the problem to this function of code, but I do not understand why this is happening...

```
void checkDB()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc=0;
    size_t i;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    char buffer[MAX_PATH*4];
    int len;
    GetModuleFileNameW(hModule, path, MAX_PATH);
    len =lstrlenW(path);
    path[len-13]='\0';
    buffer[0]='\0';

    wcscat_s(path,sizeof(path),L"test.db\0");
    GetFileAttributes(path);
    if(INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == GetFileAttributes(path) && GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        wcstombs_s(&i,buffer,sizeof(buffer), path, wcslen(path) );
        rc= sqlite3_open(buffer,&db);

        rc=sqlite3_exec(db,"create table Recipe (Recipe_Num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Recipe_Image VARCHAR(30), Recipe_Name VARCHAR(200))",NULL,0,&zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        rc=sqlite3_exec(db,"create table Recipe_Step (Recipe_Num INTEGER, Step_Num INTEGER, Description VARCHAR(2000))",NULL,0,&zErrMsg);
        if(rc!=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
        else
        {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete test?

Comment: Do you still have that error if you comment out `sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);`

Comment: As a side note, you never freed the `zErrMsg` passed to the **second** sqlite3_exec, so you have a memory leak there.

Comment: The `len-13` is worrisome.  You seem to have made an executable that breaks if you rename it.

Comment: I get this error even is sqlite3_free is there or not. The len-13 is temporary.
Download for project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gk3cfczzm64ph47/RecipeApp.rar
Code is in RecipeApp.cpp

Comment: For some reason if I replace 
wcscat_s(path,sizeof(path),L"test.db\0");
by
wcscat_s(path,L"test.db\0");
it seems to compile correctly, which is weird because in the documentation it says that you can provide the size of it as parameter 2:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: There is also a template overload which can deduce destination size automatically. If you provide the size explicitly, you should use `_countof` instead of `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be possible that you are overruning some raw `char`/`WCHAR` buffer?

I'd suggest you modernizing your code and using **robust string classes**, like `std::wstring` or `CString[W]` with their operator overloads, instead of raw arrays and raw C string functions like `wcscat_s()` (which you are misusing: you should pass `_countof(path)` instead of `sizeof(path)`, because the "size" must be expressed in `WCHAR`s, not in bytes).

And to convert from Unicode UTF-16 to ANSI/MBCS you can use [ATL helpers like `CW2A`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of `wcstombs_s()`.

e.g.:

```
// Assume Unicode builds, so GetModuleFileName is actually GetModuleFileNameW,
// CString is CStringW, etc.

CString strPath;
WCHAR* pszPath = strPath.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH);
GetModuleFileName(hModule, pszPath, MAX_PATH);
// check GetModuleFileName()'s return value...
strPath.ReleaseBuffer();

// Operate on strPath using operator+= to concatenate strings, etc.
strPath += L"test.db";

....

if(INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == GetFileAttributes(strPath) && GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
    // Convert from UTF-16 to ANSI
    CW2A buffer(strPath);
    rc = sqlite3_open(buffer, &db);
    ....

}
```

---

Moreover, you are leaking string memory because you don't call `sqlite3_free(zErrMsg)` after the second call to `sqlite3_exec()`. I'd suggest using the RAII pattern and the power of C++ destructors to try to write code that *automatically* frees resources. 
You could write a simple wrapper on those strings, that calls `sqlite3_free()` in the destructor, e.g.:

```
class SqlLiteErrorMsg
{
public:   
    SqlLiteErrorMsg()
       : errorMsg(nullptr)
    {}

    ~SqlLiteErrorMsg()
    {
        sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
    }

    char** GetAddressOf()
    {
        return &errorMsg;
    }    

    char* Get()
    {
        return errorMsg;
    }

private:
    // Ban copy
    SqlLiteErrorMsg(const SqlLiteErrorMsg&);
    SqlLiteErrorMsg& operator=(const SqlLiteErrorMsg&);

    char* errorMsg;
};
```

A similar wrapper could be built around the `sqlite3*` pointer.

Comment: I'm trying to make this as lightweight as possible with the least amount of dependencies. ATL and .net framework is something I want to avoid

Comment: ATL is very useful and very lightweight (comparison with .NET Framework doesn't make sense).